# Preprocessor macro defined in .config file is not visible in c file

Tags: c, makefile, macros, preprocessor

I have preprocessor macro in .config file as below

```
CONFIG_IDENTIFIER=y
```

Then, the Makefile contents are as below

```
-include .config
OBJ += ./src/myfile.o
....
myapp: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o myapp $(OBJS)
    @$(E) "  LD " $@
```

Then in ./src/myfile.c file, I try to use the perprocessor macro as below,

```
#ifdef CONFIG_IDENTIFIER
.... /* Compiler does not execute in here */
....
#endif
```

But not able to get the preprocessor macro definition in ./src/myfile.c file. Any help on this?

Comment: If it is a macro then it is not assigned a value like that: `#define CONFIG_IDENTIFIER`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have preprocessor macro in .config file as below
>
> ```
> CONFIG_IDENTIFIER=y
> ```

This defines a variable local to the Makefile. It does *not* define a C-preprocessor macro.

To make it a C-preprocessor macro you could adjust the Makefile like this:

```
-include .config
CFLAGS += -DCONFIG_IDENTIFIER=$(CONFIG_IDENTIFIER)
....
```

Answer (score 1):

`CONFIG_IDENTIFIER` is not a preprocessor macro, it's a make variable, just like `OBJS`.